# Network is unreachable after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, yocto, ethernet, ifconfig

This is the output of *ifconfig* on my Yocto embedded Linux board (I am using eth0.2 interface):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:dc:7a:3b:e9:f8  
      inet6 addr: fe80::fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:b07:5d28:764:fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10164 errors:14 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:14
      TX packets:12576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2661192 (2.5 MiB)  TX bytes:6310390 (6.0 MiB)

eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:dc:7a:3b:e9:f8  
      inet addr:192.168.1.65  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:b07:5d28:764:fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10148 errors:0 dropped:416 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11622 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2415854 (2.3 MiB)  TX bytes:6199551 (5.9 MiB)
```

However, this is the output I get after a *reboot* command:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:dc:7a:3b:e9:f8  
      inet6 addr: fe80::fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8836 errors:22 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:22
      TX packets:10417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2404061 (2.2 MiB)  TX bytes:4115640 (3.9 MiB)

eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:dc:7a:3b:e9:f8  
      inet addr:192.168.1.65  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2001:b07:5d28:764:fadc:7aff:fe3b:e9f8/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8836 errors:0 dropped:326 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9648 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2191997 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:4018664 (3.8 MiB)
```

The only difference I can see, it that the "Scope:Global" entry in eth0 is missing after a software reboot. When this occurs, pinging e.g.: 1.1.1.1 gives me "**Network is unreachable**", though I can still reach the board locally through 192.168.1.65.

The only way to get everything back to normal is to unplug the power supply and then plug it back. It seems to me like the network interface is not restarted when I issue a reboot command (the LEDs on the Ethernet interfaces do not turn off).

How can I solve this? Please tell me if you need any more details.

Comment: Looks more like a routing problem - you should check whether the default gateway for 0.0.0.0/0 is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Zac67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7988287/zac67) I have been able to solve the routing issue by adding

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0.2
```

to */etc/rc.local*.

Please, feel free to comment if you think there is a better permanent solution for this.